# Resolução da imagem no Carousel dinamico

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, webforms

estou tendo problemas nas resolução das imagens que vem dentro do carrossel, tem como setar um padrao pelo css ou javascript ? segue a imagens [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

segue o meu codigo aspx:

```
  <div id="paginas">
        <div class="sliderFrame">
           <div id="slider">
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phFotos"></asp:PlaceHolder>

            </div>
        </div>
```

*obs coloquei * pois nao carregava as tags

.CS:

```
public partial class ImovelDetalhe : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private ImovelBo _imovelBo;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                carregarInformacoes();
            }
        }

        private void carregarInformacoes()
        {
            int codigoImovel = 0;
            Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["CodImovel"], out codigoImovel);

            _imovelBo = new ImovelBo();
            var imovel = _imovelBo.ObterDetalhe(codigoImovel);

            if (imovel != null)
            {
                lblDescricao.Text = imovel.Descricao;
                lblOperacao.Text = imovel.Operacao;
                lblCidade.Text = imovel.Cidade;
                lblLocalizacao.Text = imovel.Localizacao;
                lblTipoImovel.Text = imovel.Tipo;
                lblQtDormitorios.Text = imovel.QntDormitorio.ToString();
                lblValor.Text = imovel.Valor.ToString("#,##0.00");

                if (imovel.Fotos != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in imovel.Fotos)
                    {
                        Image foto = new Image();
                        foto.Width = 700;
                        foto.Height = 306;
                        foto.ImageUrl = item;
                        phFotos.Controls.Add(foto);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*obs setei os tamanhos aqui mesmo assim nao deu certo 
 queria deixar mais ou menos assim :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

desde ja agradeço

Comment: Ola André, você aplicou o width/height e mesmo assim não aconteceu nada? É isso? Você deseja expandi a foto como na segunda imagem?

Comment: Fiz o teste com o mesmo código e a imagem redimensionou sem problema, verifique por favor se os divs externos ao placeholder não estão influenciando. O código em C# funciona. Ta com cara de ajuste de CSS. :)

Comment: Entao apliquei width e height e mesmo assim nao surtiu efeito tem fotos que se enquadra perfeitamente no slideshow e outra que ficam muito aplicadas ... e o css ja fiz as alterações e nao surtiu efeito

Comment: Teria como eu ter acesso as imagens que você usa para testar e o html/css? Para eu testar de forma mais fiel o exemplo.

Comment: Rodrigo, consegui resolver esse problema add um hendler para imagens, muito obrigado pela a sua ajuda

Comment: Opa André, que bom que achou uma solução, as vezes só mudando o caminho para resolver mesmo kkk. Sucesso no projeto!

Comment: Obrigado parceiro! Boa semana